# MySQL connector not working without net connection

Tags: mysql, vb.net, mysql-connector

I am creating small database program using MySQL and VB.Net. I am using WampServer for MySQL and MySQL 6.9.8 connector. All code is working fine when I am connected to the internet but when I disconnect, it shows me a "database not found" error. My database is stored locally in Wamp phyMyAdmin

Here is my code

```vb
Try
    If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        conn.ConnectionString = "DATABASE=" & My.Settings.myDB & ";" _
            & "SERVER=" & My.Settings.myServer & ";user id=" & My.Settings.myUsername _
            & ";password=" & My.Settings.myPassword & ";port=" & _
            My.Settings.myPort & ";charset=utf8;Convert Zero Datetime=True"
        conn.Open()
    End If
Catch myerror As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Error Connecting to the database", "Error Database Server", _
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End
End Try
```

Here is my other code;

```vb
Try
    mdlCon.conn.Open()
    Dim rd As MySqlDataReader
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    cmd.CommandText = "select * from studentdeatil Order by sid DESC"
    cmd.Connection = mdlCon.conn
    rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
    dt.Load(rd)
    rd.Close()
    For Each rowD As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim dgvRow As String() = New String() {rowD.Item(3), rowD.Item(1), rowD.Item(2), rowD.Item(4), rowD.Item(5), rowD.Item(6), rowD.Item(7), rowD.Item(8), rowD.Item(9), rowD.Item(10), "", "OLD", rowD.Item(0)}
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgvRow)
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Comment: Instead of displaying an useless message in your catch block, try to display the value of _myerror.Message_ . We could get an useful tip to understand what's going on here.

Comment: When i connect to internet its work perfectly and when i disconnect its show me Exception message "database not selected"